# signinSilent not working (openID Connect)

Tags: openid-connect

I have the oidc implemented in my React Project.

It works to `signinRedirect` and to `signoutRedirect` , also `automaticSilentRenew` is set to true and works.

The issue is that the `signinSilent` is not working.

I'm logged in another tab with a valid token and In current tab I receive:
[image]

My Authorization file contains all the redirect uri (redirect_uri, post_logout_redirect_uri, silent_redirect_uri etc)

On page load I'm calling an init() function which contains the logic for silent sign in using oidc:

```
{
    return _mgr
        .signinRedirectCallback()
        .then(user => {
            // if this is a signin redirect action then set the user info
            console.log('signinRedirectCallback: Successful redirect signin.', user);
            return (_user = user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // otherwise this is a page reload
            console.log('signinRedirectCallback: Page reload.', error);

            // Execute logic to check if the user is still authenticated, it invokes a silent signin call which happens through an iFrame.
            return _mgr
                .signinSilent({ redirect_uri: _config.oidc.silent_redirect_uri })
                .then(user => {
                    // if user is still authenticated then set the user info
                    console.log('signinSilent:  Page reload. Successful silent signin.', user);
                    user.profile.given_name = user.profile.preferred_username;
                    return (_user = user);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // otherwise unset user info
                    console.log('signinSilent: Page reload.', error);
                    _user = null;
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                });
        })
}
```

How can I remove this "Frame window time out" are and make the silent login successful?

Answer (score 0):

Which Authorization Server are you using and what token storage model (in memory, session storage etc)?

It could be related to the AS trying to render a login page - even though OIDC client sends prompt=none on silent redirects.